# How to retrieve JSON variables from a AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

When I tried to fetch the values from a JSON response, I stucked up. Here is my code

**Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'checkvotes.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
     // want to fetch UP and DOWN variables from JSON here
     }
 });
```

**AJAX Response from PHP**

```
{"sample":[{"id":"1","message":"my message","up":"200","down":"34"}]}
```

Comment: alert(data.id); which says undefined

Comment: The object doesn't have an id property, it only has a sample property (which has a length 1 array as its value which…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'checkvotes.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       var up = data.sample[0].up;
       var down = data.sample[0].down;
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `data.sample[0].up` and `data.sample[0].down`. If in doubt, use this JavaScript to emulate the call:

```
var data = {"sample":[{"id":"1","message":"my message","up":"200","down":"34"}]};
```

Run that in a debugger and examine `data`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var up = data['sample'][0]['up'],
    down = data['sample'][0]['down']
```

just print a console.log(data) to inspect your json